# Melting butter on pancakes and syrup

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

I would like the butter to keep more of it's square shape around the top, but have some melted around it, on the syrup. How would I adjust the settings to do this? I would also like to know if I can put the butter / liquid directly on the syrup / liquid or do I need to convert the syrup to a mesh. I've been converting it to a mesh.

Comment: please show us your settings or even better your blend file. We have no idea what settings you used or how you did that...

Comment: is it supposed to be animated? You could play with some transparency on the butter borders if you want it to fade into the syrup?

Comment: No it's not animated. I tried working with the transparency, but it's physically not melting around the bottom enough without loosing it's shape around the top. I'll upload the blend file today when the simulation is done again.

Comment: I think I would duplicate the object and make a new material for it.  Sculpt it down into a puddle and leave them intersecting

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the velocity setting instead of trying to set a certain velocity, and it kept it's shape, with melted butter around the bottom. It also took a lot less time to run the simulation.